Calculate mean values of the past x years for every month
I have historical data from 2012 to 2023. I am trying to calculate the average for every month during these years to build a 'reference year' or 'baseline'. My DataFrame (final_df) looks like this:
                Timestamp             bruttoPower [kW]      nettoPower [kW]     
0               2012-01-01 00:00:00   1501.500000           375.375000          
1               2012-01-01 01:00:00   1488.833333           372.208333          
2               2012-01-01 02:00:00   1626.833333           406.708333          
3               2012-01-01 03:00:00   1350.333333           337.583333          
4               2012-01-01 04:00:00   1424.000000           356.000000          
...             ...                   ...                   ...                 
105187          2023-12-31 19:00:00   3301.758391           763.500000          
105188          2023-12-31 20:00:00   2322.399977           592.500000              
105189          2023-12-31 21:00:00   3393.225006           861.000000              
105190          2023-12-31 22:00:00   3784.991643           952.000000              
105191          2023-12-31 23:00:00   3661.591654           950.500000          
105192 rows × 5 columns

I tried doing the same as in this post, since is basically the same problem, but it didn't work: Pandas, how to calculate mean values of the past n years for every month
I also tried asking ChatGPT, but its suggestion didn't work either:
final_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

final_df['Year'] = final_df['Timestamp'].dt.year
final_df['Month'] = final_df['Timestamp'].dt.month

df_new = final_df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).sum()

df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)

display(df_new)

I am expecting something like this:
(The values are not true, I don't know how much they would be)
    Month   brutto Power [kW]   netto Power [kW]    
0   Jan     1501.500000         375.375000          
1   Feb     1488.833333         372.208333          
2   Mar     1626.833333         406.708333          
3   Apr     1350.333333         337.583333          
4   May     1424.000000         356.000000          
... ...     ...                 ...                 
10  Nov     3393.225006         861.000000          
11  Dec     3784.991643         952.000000          



IIUC you can do (using only data from the question, with real data the final dataframe should have 12 rows):
import calendar

out = (
    df.groupby(df.pop("Timestamp").dt.month)
    .mean()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"Timestamp": "Month"})
)
out["Month"] = out["Month"].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])

print(out)

Prints:
  Month  bruttoPower [kW]  nettoPower [kW]
0   Jan       1478.300000          369.575
1   Dec       3292.793334          823.900


Do you know how I can do the same but instead of having the average for each month, have the average for each hour of each day? Meaning the average of all years for 01-01 00:00:00:00 , then average of all years for 01-01 01:00:00:00 and so on until the average of all years for 12-31 23:00:00:00.
I tried changing dt.month for dt.hour and out["Month"] = out["Month"].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x]) for baseline_df["Hour"] = baseline_df["Hour"].apply(lambda x: f"{x:02}" if 0 <= x <= 23 else x)
But I am getting an average for every hour in general, not every hour of each day.

Or if I change it to dt.date and baseline_df["Date"] = baseline_df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) I get the average for each day but I'm missing the hours.

@snkm Hello, I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow where you put what you have/tried and I try to look at it.

Thanks! Here my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78505987/analyse-historical-data-average-of-every-hour-of-every-day-over-a-number-of-yea
